# What would I call this 'attitude'?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrases, expressions, idioms

A friend of mine has a bad habit of undermining people who are not the best in their respective fields.

If in a car-race, player A wins out of 26 players (A,B,C...Z). He would claim 'A' to be the best but then he would start calling all the other players stupid, pathetic, unworthy of respect heck! even a small appreciation and acts as if the other players don't even deserve to live on this planet.

In every competitive aspect of life, someone would lose and someone would win. That's the nature of the law. The person who came out as 2nd perhaps lagged by an insignificant time interval. He would start to worship the winner and would start calling all the other players as 'worst player' each (starting from B,C,D,E,F...Z).

There are only two categories: Winner(A) and losers(B,C,D...Z) with absolutely no distinction between, let's say player 'D' and 'V'. I would like to add that the field may be and usually is something which he knows very little of.

What do we call this attitude? I would prefer a colloquial word.

The sentence which I would like you to fill up would be:

> Stop acting so ______; It's not okay to be so critical about the other
>   players.

If you have any alternative equivalent of this sentence, possibly humorous, do suggest. Thank you.

Comment: *Mean* is the term I'd use.

Comment: I would be very tempted to use the word "jerkass" to describe him.

Comment: Stop searching for a better word and find a better friend before you come in second in something.

Comment: I would describe that sort of reasoning as “black and white”, but no single term comes to mind.

Comment: The term is called ***having an attitude***.

Comment: Stop acting so Ricky Bobby...https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XPFMzskXZvY

Answer (score 2):

The closest I can think of is *dismissive*. To be dismissive of someone or a group of people is to refuse to give proper consideration to their merits. Having said that, this seems to lack the venom of your example.

http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/dismissive

Answer (score 1):

Some words you might use are *judgmental*, *petty*, or *spiteful*.

Answer (score 1):

Or, to use a very British expression  -  your friend is not 'playing the game', he's 'unsporting'.

Try reminding him of Kipling's advice:

*And when that one great scorer comes to write against your name,*

*It'll matter not who won or lost,*

*But how you played the game*.

Comment: Good! Just a gentle reminder: It's not necessarily just sports. It could rather be an students' exam or as dumb as it gets, a TV episode like Powerpuff girls where he considers the red to be the most powerful and other two powerless even though the show never differentiate between the trio.

Comment: Kipling's advice applies to life in general. You can be a "bad sport" about anything, not just sports.

Comment: @BrianHitchcock But increased professionalism and the huge amounts of money now involved in serious sport, has removed a lot of the old spirit. I remember when Wimbledon was amateur only, and it was far better for it.

Answer (score 1):

Stop acting so [**obnoxious**](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/obnoxious) *adjective*: unpleasant in a way that makes people feel offended, annoyed, or disgusted. (Merriam-Webster *online*)

Answer (score 1):

The person is being **discriminatory** "making or showing an unfair or prejudicial distinction between different categories of people or things" and **invidious**: "tending to cause discontent, animosity".

Answer (score 0):

*Unsportsmanlike* comes to mind here, as it is specific to the context of winning/losing.

Merriam-Webster:

http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/unsportsmanlike